# How to transform list elements into percentages

Tags: python, list

I have this code:

```
dice_rolls = []
      for i in range(0, dice_amount):
         dice_rolls.append(random.randint(1,dice_face))
```

and i wanted it to display for example: there was 5 number 1, 6 number 2, etc... And, if possible, say what percentage of the list is what element. For example: 1% was 5, 6% was seven, etc

Comment: Please complete your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count` [method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_count.asp) to get the number of elements for each dice roll.

Example with your code (dice rolls from 1 to 6) :

```py
import random

if __name__ == "__main__":

    count = 10
    dice_rolls = list()

    random.seed()

    for i in range(count):
        dice_rolls.append(random.randint(1, 6))

    print(f"Dice rolls: {dice_rolls}")
    for i in range(6):
        print(f"Dice = {i + 1} - Count = {dice_rolls.count(i + 1)}")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. find the unique elemnts in that list and store it in a seperate list

   ```
   # traverse for all elements
    for x in list1:
        # check if exists in unique_list or not
        if x not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(x)
   ```

unique list contains all the unique elements.

2. Now use the unique list and count the occourances of unique elements :
   (idk why but this part is not indenting as code)

   import operator as op
   for x in unique_list:
   print(f"{x} has occurred {op.countOf(list1, x)} times")
   val_list.append(x,op.countOf(list1,x))

3 Now you  have the unique elements and tthe occourance now find the percentage by

value_1_percent = (value_1_count/len(original _list))*100

Answer (score 1):

As simple as possible:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys,random


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #all helpful variables
    help_dictionary ={}
    dictionary_with_percents ={}
    dice_amount = 100
    diceface = 6
    dice_rolls = []

    #your code
    for i in range(0, dice_amount):
        dice_rolls.append(random.randint(1,diceface))

    #lets check how many times each face occured
    for i in dice_rolls:
        help_dictionary[i]= dice_rolls.count(i)
    
    #lets check what is the percentage for each face
    for face , amount in help_dictionary.items():
        dictionary_with_percents[face] = str((amount/dice_amount)*100)+'%'

    #lets print the result
    print (dictionary_with_percents)
```

You can also use dict comprehension instead of for loops, here ist only my idea ;-)